# Solve ODE with TensorFlow in Python

Tags: python, neural-network, numerical-methods, differential-equations

In python, how to use neural network with TensorFlow to solve ordinary differential equations，and now I have an ODE,

[image: Links to the image of differential equations]

I'm trying to get the numerical solution and graph it,and I defined following,

```py
def ode(t, x):
   a=0.3
   k=5.1
   b=6.0
   c=4.3
   return k*math.exp(-b*t)*math.cos(c*t)-a*x
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to use a NN to solve this equation, not use the solution as some kind of node or layer inside a NN? Have you found any examples where this was done successfully and more efficiently than using scipy.integrate.odeint?

Comment: I know how to use scipy.Integrate.odeint to solve this ODE, but I want to try to use NN to solve it and express it in the form of image

Comment: What do you mean in the form of an image?

Answer (score 0):

To use a NN, you need to rephrase your problem as a minimisation problem. I'm sure more intelligent people than me have worked out how to do that, but here's a way I just came up with:

- Start with a 1-D (your system is 1-D) mesh of points, all initialised to 0 (this will become the solution).
- Calculate the gradient between each pair of points numerically (also all 0).
- Subtract from this the value of the gradient at each value, calculated from your function ode(t, x) above.
- Use the NN to minimise the absolute value of this function, by varying the value of the solution at each x.

So the input to the NN is an x-value, and the output is a t-value. The loss function should be defined in terms of minimising the difference between your solution and the ode.